# How to get Started with google map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I m quite new to google map API. When I searched about it google displayed many categories of map API. Many version and so on. So I confused and started this thread.

Actually I want to do:
I have multiple places with latitude and altitude. I want to display few of them on the map with the pin (the balloon like spot on the map). that's it.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: GoogleMaps is very easy to implement into your website.. But it can get quite complicated because theres so many things you can do with it.. Try following this one: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use this one, Google Maps JavaScript API V3:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps use a large range of API's due to the lack of information in the post it is hard to gauge how to help with this questions.

I would advise you check the URL above, or provide further information about the results you wish to acquire from the API so we can help you further.

Thanks